# Samba - accessing LAN shared folders - Troubleshooting

Tags: networking, samba

I know this is a very basic question, and I apologize in advance, but I'm having trouble accessing folders shared via Windows, on what I understood to be the SAMBA protocol.

I have at least two servers running on my local network : one windows PC and my router.

However I am unable to connect to any of them (router here):

```bsh
$ smbclient //192.168.0.254/Freebox
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED
```

`findsmb` only returns my local computer (but I've read that it might be normal behavior?).

`nmap` tells me that the server is running: `139/tcp  open     netbios-ssn`.

One possibly important detail is that the router is running a deprecated samba version v1.0.

Therefore my question is:

- is there any way to scan the network and discover the samba servers?
- why can I not connect ?
- more generally, what are the tools that I can use to debug what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! As I suspected, it was due to samba v1.0 being used, which was deprecated.

Solution was to add `--option='client min protocol=NT1'`:

```bsh
smbclient //192.168.0.254/My\ Book -A ~/.boxcredentials --option='client min protocol=NT1'
```

as explained here: https://forum.hackthebox.eu/discussion/2848/having-smb-enum-issues-read-this.